# How to differentiate context values if their state changed in React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context, react-state

```js
const someFunction = () = {
...
const { data, setData, activeIndex, setActiveIndex } = useContext(MusicContext);
 

  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(" useEffect called");
    
    // another component called setData or setActiveIndex which resulted here  
    // how to compare data to its prevState if it changed  
    // how to compare activeIndex to its prevState if it changed  

  }, [activeIndex, data]);
...
}
```

Above is some function which has a useEffect for two different context variables

`data` is an object proptype {} and `activeIndex` is a number

how do i compare `data` to its prevState if it changed?
how do i  compare `activeIndex` to its prevState if it changed?
can i do it in a single useEffect block and need to open multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `useRef` to store the last seen value.  This is often extracted into a "[usePrevious](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)" custom hook.

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Now in your component, you can check against the previous value.

```
const SomeFunction = () = {
  ...
  const { data, setData, activeIndex, setActiveIndex } = useContext(MusicContext);
 
  const prevData = usePrevious( data );
  const prevActiveIndex = usePrevious( activeIndex );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if ( data !== prevData ) {
      // do something
    }
    if ( activeIndex !== prevActiveIndex ) {
      // do something
    }

  }, [activeIndex, data]);
...
}
```